How to Prevent Flashing of "Verify Your Email" Banner in React When Loading User Data
I have a React application where I display a "Verify your email" banner if the user is not verified. The user's verification status is stored in local storage and is loaded into the application state on component mount. However, when the user is already verified, the banner still flashes for a millisecond before disappearing.
Current Setup:
User data, including isVerified, is loaded from local storage into the application state when the component mounts.
The banner is conditionally rendered based on the isVerified status.
Problem
When the component mounts, the isVerified status briefly shows as false or undefined, causing the banner to flash momentarily even for verified users.
What is the best practice to prevent the flashing of the "Verify your email" banner when loading user data from local storage in a React application? How should I implement the chosen solution effectively?
Possible Solutions:

Using a Loading State Introduce a loading state to manage the asynchronous
loading process. Conditionally render user-related UI elements basedon the loading state. Ensure that the banner is only shown when isVerified is definitively false and the loading state is false.
Setting isVerified to undefined. Initialize isVerified as undefined. Check its value to determine if the data has been loaded.    Conditionally render the banner based on the defined status of isVerified.
Skeleton Loading State. Use skeleton screens to indicate data
loading.
Suspense and React.lazy. Use React Suspense and lazy loading for
components dependent on user data.


isVerified is essentially three-state here: unknown (not loaded), verified, not verified, or in TypeScript types, bool | undefined Only render the banner if isVerified === false.

Option 1 is the most straightforward way to handle it.

Initialize the loading state: Add a state variable to keep track of the loading status.
Set the loading state: Set the loading state to true initially and then set it to false after loading the user data from local storage.
Conditional rendering: Render the banner only if the loading state is false and the user is not verified.

Code example:
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [isVerified, setIsVerified] = useState(null); // Initialize as null to represent loading state
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); // Loading state

  useEffect(() => {
    // Simulate loading data from local storage
    const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("userData"));
    if (userData && userData.isVerified !== undefined) {
      setIsVerified(userData.isVerified);
    } else {
      setIsVerified(false); // Default to false if no user data found
    }
    setIsLoading(false); // Data has been loaded
  }, []);

  if (isLoading) {
    return null; // Or a loading spinner, placeholder, etc.
  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {!isVerified && (
        <div className="verify-banner">
          Verify your email
        </div>
      )}
      Hello World :)
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;


